# using XDebug in a Dockerized PHP on mac OS

Tags: php, shell, docker, xdebug

## The issue

I'm not able to debug using Xdebug from a Dockerized container on macOS.

I ve read very carefully : [XDebug Remote configuration](https://xdebug.org/docs/remote),  [Nikita Nikitin post](http://manual.pohape.ru/xdebug/) And all the proposed solutions on Stackoverflow and Github. I'm still blocked..

### In the container

I can connect to the container `bash -c "clear && docker exec -it DockerizedSample sh"`

It confirms that XDebug is installed.

```
# php -m -c
[PHP Modules]
Core
...
xdebug
...

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug
```

And its configuration seems valid.

```
# tail /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
```

## The docker file

```
FROM bartlebys/php-apache-mongo:latest
MAINTAINER Benoit Pereira da Silva <https://pereira-da-silva.com>

COPY /html /var/www/html/

################################
## CONFIGURE AND ENABLE XDEBUG #
################################

#Erase the current Configuration of xdebug
RUN     echo "" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

#Configure XDEBUG
RUN     HOST_IN_CONTAINER_IP=$(/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }')\
        &&echo "xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
        && echo "xdebug.remote_host=$HOST_IN_CONTAINER_IP" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
        && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
        && echo "xdebug.remote_mode=req" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
        && echo "xdebug.remote_port=9000" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
        && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini\
        && echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini

# Enable XDEBUG's extension
RUN    echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

## The run script

```
#!/bin/sh

# Stop the container
echo "Stop "
docker stop DockerizedSample

# Delete the container
echo "Remove "
docker rm DockerizedSample

# Delete the image if necessary
docker rmi dockerizedsampleimage:latest

# Build the youdubserver image
echo "Building with the current source"
docker build -t dockerizedsampleimage:latest .

# Run DockerizedSample container
echo "Run container "

# Run the container once.
# then grab the IP of the HOST in the container
# stop and relaunch with the good IP
docker run  -d --name DockerizedSample dockerizedsampleimage
HOST_IN_CONTAINER_IP=$(docker exec DockerizedSample /sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }')
docker stop DockerizedSample
docker rm DockerizedSample

# Run the debuggable container
docker run  -e PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=Dockerized"\
            -e XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_host=$HOST_IN_CONTAINER_IP"\
            -p 27017:27017 \
            -p 8001:80\
            -d --name DockerizedSample dockerizedsampleimage\

# Start mongod
echo "Start mongod "
docker exec DockerizedSample service mongod start

echo "IP in Docker Host"
echo "$HOST_IN_CONTAINER_IP"

echo "Local IP"
ipconfig getifaddr en0

# Open localhost in a browser on macOS
if [[ "$OSTYPE" =~ ^darwin ]];
    then open http://localhost:8001/
fi;
```

## How to Reproduce the issue

1. Download [Php-Apache-Mongo/zip/master](https://codeload.github.com/Bartlebys/Php-Apache-Mongo/zip/master)
2. Go to the PHPStorm folder and run the shell script `./run.sh`

After building the image (may take a few minutes) and running the container it should open a browser on http://localhost:8001/

## My current testing environment

- PhpStorm 2016.2.1
- Build #PS-162.1889.1, built on August 23, 2016
- You have perpetual fallback license for this version
- JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b216 x86_64
- JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- macOS Sierra **10.12 (16A323)**
- Docker for mac Installed from the official [docker for mac](https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg) **Version 1.12.1** (build: 12133) 2d5b4d9c3daa089e3869e6355a47dd96dbf39856

Answer (score 1):

Your solution can be greatly simplified since the release of Docker 18.03.

The `host.docker.internal` DNS name has been made available to running docker containers. These DNS entries hold the IP address of the docker host.

So instead of
`xdebug.remote_host=172.17.0.1`
you can do
`xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal`

You can also remove the part of the run script that runs the docker container merely to get the host's IP address.

Comment: Seems this this is now `host.docker.internal` as stated in https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#httphttps-proxy-support

Answer (score 0):

Basically for the remote debugging the extension does nothing, but setting the cookie XDEBUG_SESSION to a value of an idekey. In your "complicated" case I'd better check the following 4 things, that came into my mind first:

1. Your xdebug.remote_port=9000.

If the port #9000 is occupied on the server side (the side, where you use your IDE) by php-fpm, the IDE can not start listening incoming connections. Simply 9000 is the default port for fpm, and this often becomes a common mistake. And that's why I use the port #10000.

2. docker run -e PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=Dockerized"

PHP_IDE_CONFIG here is not an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). This is actually a  parameter of the [fastcgi_param](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_param) directive of an nginx config.

3. Use xdebug.remote_log=/path/to/xdebug_remote.log
4. Personally I prefer to use old software. So I'm not a good helper here, but as far as I heard Phpstorm now uses a different configuration for remote debugging.

Comment: Thank you very much Nikita.  I've found the solution and it is not so complex. I will answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found the solution.It was not so complex. I ve used 'telnet' to determine if the container was able to reach the host on the 9000. And it was not. The confusion was coming from the remote host IP. You must use your localhost IP!!!

```
HOST_IP=$(ifconfig en0 | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | awk '{print $2}')

docker run  -e PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=DockerLocal"\
                -e XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM"\
                -e XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_host=$HOST_IP"\
                -p 27017:27017 \
                -p 8001:80\
                -d --name DockerizedSample dockerizedsampleimage
```

Check [details on hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/r/bartlebys/php-apache-mongo/)
Or directly on [the github repository of Bartleby's Php-Apache-Mongo](https://github.com/Bartlebys/Php-Apache-Mongo)